# How do I resolve timeout issue for videos conversions in AWS elemental video converter

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-elemental

At video conversion with the lambda function in Elemental Video Converter, some video conversions stops for time out issue, and for others the conversion goes without problems, how can I solve this problem, Thank you

The problem is random, I couldn't find an explanation